# Has anyone seen a bracelet like this one? (WW2 Cairo)

Tags: world-war-two

My mother-in-law has this bracelet. It was her father's who died in Egypt in WW2. We'd love to know more about it. Has anyone ever seen one of these?
[image: Egyptian bracelet from ww2]

Comment: It is interesting that the bracelet has no obvious Cairo landmarks. No pyramids, no sphinx. The only distinct building seems to be the yellow one to the right of the Arab inscription. I am not particularly good with reading Arabic letters, but does this inscription mean anything? Or might it be just gibberish?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I really don't know. I just found it interesting especially that it's from ww2